# when I used google you tube API get search result it is give 403 error

Tags: angular, api, http-status-code-403, angular-observable

// When I get a response from youtube API it gives me a 403 error in below code service and components, it gives a response with 404 error with message "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."

```
export class YoutubeServiceService {
          constructor(
            private http: HttpClient,
            @Inject(YOUTUBE_API_KEY) private apiKey: string,
            @Inject(YOUTUBE_API_URL) private apiUrl: string
          ) {}

          search(query: string): Observable<SearchResult[]> {
            const params: string = [
              `q=${query}`,
              `part=${this.apiKey}`,
              `part=snippet`,
              `type=video`,
              `maxResults=8`,
            ].join('&');
            const queryUrl = `${this.apiUrl}?${params}`;
            return this.http.get(queryUrl).pipe(map((response) => {
              return <any>response['items'].map((item) => {
                console.log('raw items', item);
                return new SearchResult({
                  id: item.id.videoId,
                  title: item.snippet.title,
                  description: item.snippet.description,
                  thumbnailUrl: item.snippet.thumbnailUrl.high.url,
                });
              });
            })
            );
          }
        }
```

// this is a search component, where I want to search any strings in the input box to get data

```
 import  
            {
                  Component,
                  OnInit,
                  Output,
                  ElementRef,
                  EventEmitter,
                } from '@angular/core';
                import { SearchResult } from '../search-result.model';
                import { YoutubeServiceService } from '../youtube-service/youtube-service.service';
                import { Observable, fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
                import { map, filter, debounceTime, switchAll ,tap} from 'rxjs/operators';
                @Component({
                  selector: 'app-search-box',
                  template: `<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search"
                  autofocus >`
                })
        export class SearchBoxComponent implements OnInit {
          @Output() loading: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
          @Output() results: EventEmitter<SearchResult[]> = new EventEmitter<
            SearchResult[]
          >();

          constructor(private youtube: YoutubeServiceService, private el: ElementRef) {}

          ngOnInit(): void {
            fromEvent(this.el.nativeElement, 'keyup')
            .pipe(
              map((e: any) => e.target.value), //extract the value of the input
              filter((text: string) => text.length > 1) ,// filter pout if empty
              debounceTime(250), //only once every 250s
              tap(() => this.loading.emit(true)), //enable loading
              map((query: string) => this.youtube.search(query)), //search, discarding old events if new input comes in
              switchAll()
            )
              .subscribe(
                (results: SearchResult[]) => {
                  //on sucess
                  this.loading.emit(false);
                  this.results.emit(results);
                },
                (err: any) => {
                  //on error
                  console.log(err);
                  this.loading.emit(false);
                },
                () => {
                  // on completion
                  this.loading.emit(false);
                }
              );
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `search()` function, it looks like you're setting your API key as the "part" query parameter. The YouTube Data API reference specifies that your API key should be provided in the "key" query parameter.

Try setting your `params` string like this:

```
const params: string = [
              `q=${query}`,
              `key=${this.apiKey}`,
              `part=snippet`,
              `type=video`,
              `maxResults=8`,
            ].join('&');
```

I'm assuming that `YOUTUBE_API_URL` is pointing to the /search endpoint, which you can view the documentation for at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list.